# Custom Trigger Scripts for Bot (Xcode 5 CI)

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode5, xcode-bots

I am working on setting up CI for my iOS application and I am facing some issues.

- Where is a good place to find documents on Bot? I have seen the Xcode
  help but cant find any good example, also watched the CI video from
  2013 conference
- How do i create a custom trigger script, so every    time a developer
  commits their code it will automatically trigger the    bot.
- How do I merge the code to master only if Test successfully    passes
  the bot?

Here is where I found info about trigger scripts
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/1.0/#apdE6540C63-ADB5-4B07-89B7-6223EC40B59C

> Example values are shown with each setting.   Schedule: Choose to run
>   manually, periodically, on new commits, or on **trigger scripts**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Continuous Integration Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/000-About_Continuous_Integration/about_continuous_integration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH1-SW1) available on the Apple developer website which provides detailed explanations of how to set up your CI builds. It lacks details on trigger scripts however.

For that the best documentation is found in the OSX Server scripts themselves. The term "trigger scripts" as used here by Apple refers to post-receive hooks in Git. Git event hooks can be added to the .git/hooks subdirectory of any Git repository to perform actions in response to events on the Git repository which contains them.

To see an example post-receive hook which specifically "kicks" an Xcode service to run CI builds, create a hosted Git repository on the server hosting your Xcode build service. By default, Git repositories added to an Xcode server will have a post-receive hook created automatically. In this case it is a Ruby script which `POST`s to `http://localhost/xcs/kick-commit-bots` with `repository` and `branch` form fields set to the URL of the repository (as it is configured in the Xcode service) and the branch to pull respectively.

So, create a hosted repository by following the steps outlined in the Xcode Continuous Integration Guide and then view the contents of `/Library/Server/Xcode/Repositories/git/<your project>.git/hooks/post-receive` on the Xcode server. If you host your Git projects elsewhere (e.g. BitBucket, GitHub or a linux box on your local network) you can use this file as a guide when creating your own post-receive hook in your scripting language of choice.

An example for those who don't have the option of creating a hosted repo on their build server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

##
# Copyright (c) 2014 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# IMPORTANT NOTE: This file is licensed only for use on Apple-branded
# computers and is subject to the terms and conditions of the Apple Software
# License Agreement accompanying the package this file is a part of.
# You may not port this file to another platform without Apple's written consent.
#
# IMPORTANT NOTE: This file is licensed only for use with the Wiki Server feature
# of the Apple Software and is subject to the terms and conditions of the Apple
# Software License Agreement accompanying the package this file is part of.
##

# fill in the exact URL to your repository, as entered in your OS X Server configuration
$repository_url = "file:///git/python-lrparser.git"
$repository_mode = "git"

# fill in the hostname of your OS X Server machine; this must be accessible by the server
# on which your repository is hosted; you may use "localhost" for the local machine
#server_host = "server.example.com"
$server_host = "localhost"


##########################################
## DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
##########################################

require 'net/http'

def kick(branch)
  theURL = URI("http://#{$server_host}/xcs/kick-commit-bots")
  if branch.nil?
    Net::HTTP.post_form(theURL, 'repository' => $repository_url)
  else
    Net::HTTP.post_form(theURL, 'repository' => $repository_url, 'branch' => branch)
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  # determine what branch this is a push to, if possible
  branches = []

  if $repository_mode == "git"
    $stdin.each_line do |line|
      oldrev, newrev, ref = line.strip.split
      if ref =~ %r{^refs/heads/(.+)$}
        branches.push($~[1])
      end
    end
  elsif $repository_mode == "svn" and ARGV.length >= 2
    repository = ARGV[0]
    revision = ARGV[1]
    modifiedDirs = `svnlook dirs-changed -r #{revision} #{repository}`.lines.map { |line| line.chomp }
    modifiedDirs.each do |d|
      if d =~ %r{branches/([^/]+)}
        branches.push($~[1])
      end
    end
  end

  # if we have no branch information, just kick generically
  puts "Notifying OS X Server..."
  if branches.empty?
    kick(nil)
  else
    # otherwise, do a targeted kick for each relevant branch
    branches.each do |branch|
      kick(branch)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bot's scheme, create a post build script that parses the test results.

The test results will be located here:

```
/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/Latest/output/xcodebuild_result.bundle/Info.plist
```

Once you verify that the tests pass in that plist, you can merge into master.

Then create a bot that only integrates when someone pushes to master.  I believe editing the bot's schedule has an option for polling a repo for changes.  Make sure the bot is created by an Xcode project that is currently on master.

The first bot would need to be created when Xcode is on the test branch you would create.